# I want to display buttons at the bottom of the screen and the buttons are inside linearLayout4,can someone pls tell me in this, am frustated now

Tags: android, android-layout

Problem with last linear layout containing buttons,I want to display my last linear   layout i.e. of id-linearlayout4 at the bottom of the screen,so that my buttons should come  at the bottom...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/pic5"> 

     <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"                           android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="60dip"></LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"               android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"       
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"              
 android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
 android:id="@+id/quesname" 
android:textSize="20dip"     
android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>
       </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" 
android:orientation="vertical"       
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="match_parent">
         <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" 
android:orientation="vertical"           
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="match_parent">
          <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/optionslayout" 
android:orientation="vertical"        
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="match_parent">
           </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:gravity="bottom">
         <Button android:id="@+id/prev" android:layout_width="100dip"         android:text="Previous" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
           <Button android:id="@+id/next" android:layout_marginLeft="120dip"       android:layout_width="100dip" android:text="Next" android:layout_height="wrap_content">        </Button>
       </LinearLayout>
         </LinearLayout>
          </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if you format your code like that nobody will waste his time in reading it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can insert a

```
<View android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

right before your buttons.

Or use a relative layout with alignParentBottom="true"

Answer (score 0):

You need a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout as parent; then simply drag the buttons in the layout-GUI to the bottom and they should stick there. When i am at home i am able to post "real" example code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout …>
<!-- your posted code -->
```

Dragging the button's layout parent to the bottom will produce:

```
alignParentBottom="true"
```